# Generate combination of data frame and vector

Tags: r

I know `expand.grid` is to create all combinations of given vectors. But is there a way to generate all combinations of a data frame and a vector by taking each row in the data frame as unique. For instance,

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 5:7)
c <- 9:10
```

how to create a new data frame that is the combination of `df` and `c` without expanding `df`:

```
df.c:
a b c
1 5 9
2 6 9
3 7 9
1 5 10
2 6 10
3 7 10
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may not scale when your dataframe has more than two columns per row, but you can just use `expand.grid` on the first column and then `merge` the second column in.

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 5:7)
c <- 9:10
combined <- expand.grid(a=df$a, c=c)
combined <- merge(combined, df)
> combined[order(combined$c), ]
  a  c b
1 1  9 5
3 2  9 6
5 3  9 7
2 1 10 5
4 2 10 6
6 3 10 7
```

Answer (score 14):

As for me the simplest way is `merge(df, as.data.frame(c))`

```
  a b  c
1 1 5  9
2 2 6  9
3 3 7  9
4 1 5 10
5 2 6 10
6 3 7 10
```

Comment: The simplest answer! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You could also do something like this

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(9:10, function(x,d) data.frame(d, c=x), d=df)))

# or using rbindlist as a fast alternative  to do.call(rbind,list)
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(9:10, function(x,d) data.frame(d, c=x), d=df)))
```

or

```
rbindlist(Map(data.frame, c = 9:10, MoreArgs = list(a= 1:3,b=5:7)))
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is really old but I found one more answer.

Use `tidyr`'s `expand_grid()`.

```
expand_grid(df, c)

# A tibble: 6 × 3
      a     b     c
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     5     9
2     1     5    10
3     2     6     9
4     2     6    10
5     3     7     9
6     3     7    10
```