# Combination of data.frame and vector

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, combinations

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596139/generate-combination-of-data-frame-and-vector): I need to create all combinations between a `data.frame` and a `vector`, but I need a solution for multicolumn data.frames, so I can reduce computation time for larger problems.

**Example of what I'm looking for:**

I need to create a combination of `1:3` with itself three times, but, in the end, I just need the combinations that the total `sum` is less than 5.

One way to do this is to simply use `expand.grid` and end up with 27 combinations and then just 4 combinations that obey my sum rule.

```
> x = 1:3
> b = expand.grid(x,x,x)

> rows = apply(b,1,sum)
> sum(rows < 5)
[1] 4

# Which rows obey the rule
> b[rows<5,]
   Var1 Var2 Var3
1     1    1    1
2     2    1    1
4     1    2    1
10    1    1    2
```

That works just fine, but for larger vectors or multiple combinations, instead of just 3, it takes a lot of processing. I figured that another way to do this would be dividing the task and applying a filter in each step:

```
> x = 1:3
> a = expand.grid(x,x)
> rows = apply(a,1,sum)
> sum(rows < 5)
[1] 6

# Which rows obey the rule
> a[rows<5,]
  Var1 Var2
1    1    1
2    2    1
3    3    1
4    1    2
5    2    2
7    1    3
```

And then take these 6 rows from `a` and combine them with `x`, and once again subset it according to my rule, but I don't know how to combine `a` and `x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `expand.grid` on the row numbers and `cbind` together

```
expand.grid.XY <- function(X,Y) {
  X<-as.data.frame(X);
  Y<-as.data.frame(Y);
  idx<-expand.grid(1:nrow(X),1:nrow(Y));
  cbind(X[idx[,1],,drop=FALSE],Y[idx[,2],,drop=FALSE])
}
```

With your example,

```
expand.grid.XY(a[rows<5,],x)
```

```
    Var1 Var2 Y
1      1    1 1
2      2    1 1
3      3    1 1
4      1    2 1
5      2    2 1
7      1    3 1
1.1    1    1 2
2.1    2    1 2
3.1    3    1 2
4.1    1    2 2
5.1    2    2 2
7.1    1    3 2
1.2    1    1 3
2.2    2    1 3
3.2    3    1 3
4.2    1    2 3
5.2    2    2 3
7.2    1    3 3
```

Depending on the nature of your problem, however, you might want to look into the `foreach` package, which includes a `when` filter and parallel processing possibilities.

Comment: Thanks! Very clever the idea of using the data.frame's row numbers. I will take a look at `foreach`. My real problem is essentially the same as described above, the difference is the size of the vectors and how many times I need to combine it. I am running a simulation that needs a set of parameters that, summed, cannot exceed a certain threshold.