# R loop for : repeat a vector n time

Tags: r

I have a list of 5 fixed elements such this

```
201
202
203
204
205
```

I would like to repeat it n times with the number of client=10

```
201  1
202  1
203  1
204  1
205  1
201  2
202  2
203  2
204  2
205  2
...
```

I know that I can use a loop for...How can I do that?

Comment: @JHowIX the title is a duplicate, but given this post's desired output I think something like [Generate combination of data.frame and vector](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13596139/903061) is a better dupe.

Comment: [This looks like the best dupe yet](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26768819/903061)...

Answer (score 3):

We can use `rep` with `times` for the first column and `rep` with `each` for the second column (if we need a `data.frame`)

```
n <- 5
data.frame(Col1= rep(v1, times = n),
          Col2= rep(seq(n), each=length(v1)))
#   Col1 Col2
#1   201    1
#2   202    1
#3   203    1
#4   204    1
#5   205    1
#6   201    2
#7   202    2
#8   203    2
#9   204    2
#10  205    2
#11  201    3
#12  202    3
#13  203    3
#14  204    3
#15  205    3
#16  201    4
#17  202    4
#18  203    4
#19  204    4
#20  205    4
#21  201    5
#22  202    5
#23  203    5
#24  204    5
#25  205    5
```

#### data

```
v1 <- 201:205
```

Answer (score 2):

When you want every combination of things, `expand.grid` is often nice. In this case, you want every combination of these two vectors:

```
v1 = 201:205
client = 1:10

dd = expand.grid(v1 = v1, client = client)
head(dd)
#    v1 client
# 1 201      1
# 2 202      1
# 3 203      1
# 4 204      1
# 5 205      1
# 6 201      2
```